# I am getting undefined from the Jquery function "getJSON"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
$.getJSON('SampleUserData.json', function(data) {

    var output="<ul>";
    $.each(data, function (index, val) {
        output+="<li>" + String(val.id) + " " + String(val.lastName) + "--" +"</li>";
    })

    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});
```

Returns

```
undefined undefined--
undefined undefined--
undefined undefined--
undefined undefined--
undefined undefined--
undefined undefined--
undefined undefined--
```

The JSON is below

```
[
    {
        "First Name": "Pascale",
        "Last Name": "Hood",
        "Address": "827-448 Magna Rd.",
        "City": "Burlington",
        "Zip": "38459",
        "ID": "71480845"
    },
    {
        "First Name": "Odette",
        "Last Name": "Rich",
        "Address": "7923 Pede. Rd.",
        "City": "Bothey",
        "Zip": "14394",
        "ID": "65839483"
    },
    {
        "First Name": "Christen",
        "Last Name": "Hardin",
        "Address": "390-1605 Adipiscing Street",
        "City": "Oudergem",
        "Zip": "90085",
        "ID": "78046404"
    },
    {
        "First Name": "Uma",
        "Last Name": "Cunningham",
        "Address": "313-1839 Lorem Av.",
        "City": "San Cristóbal de la Laguna",
        "Zip": "99153",
        "ID": "27367690"
    }
]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Well, `id` is not the same as `ID`, and `lastName` is not the same as `Last Name`...

Comment: What is SampleUserData.json?

Comment: You are trying to access properties that don't exist, hence you get `undefined`. Simpler example: `var foo = {}; console.log(foo.bar);`. Solution: Access the properties that exist.

Comment: @RodrigoJuarez: It's most likely the JSON the OP posted.

Comment: The getJSON call is definitely returning data, AND you are most definitely specifying the wrong keys.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few opportunities for improvement as well as the solution to the original problem you are having.

```
$.getJSON('SampleUserData.json', function(records) {
    var $ul = $('<ul></ul>');
    $ul.append(records.map(function(record) {
      return $('<li></li>').text(record['ID'] + ' ' +record['Last Name'] + '--');
    }));
    $('#userRecordContainer').empty().append($ul);
});
```

Let's recap:

1. The original problem is the keys `id` and `lastname` should be `['ID']` and `['Last Name']`.
2. Create a "virtual DOM" element in-memory. Rather than generating an html string manually, we should let the browser do it for us. It's good at html, trust it.
3. Use a better variable name than "placeholder", "data", and "value". Those names don't mean anything.
4. Use `$.fn.text` to safely append text to elements. If someone's name happens to include a `>` character or an XSS attack, your original code will break.
5. Append the generated elements rather than rebuilding an html string. This will allow you to, e.g., attach events per-element, reference each element easily later, etc.

JSFiddle for testing: http://jsfiddle.net/ht31f59m/1/

Answer (score -1):

Change JSON file to

```
{"result":
[
    {
        "First Name": "Pascale",
        "Last Name": "Hood",
        "Address": "827-448 Magna Rd.",
        "City": "Burlington",
        "Zip": "38459",
        "ID": "71480845"
    },
    {
        "First Name": "Odette",
        "Last Name": "Rich",
        "Address": "7923 Pede. Rd.",
        "City": "Bothey",
        "Zip": "14394",
        "ID": "65839483"
    },
    {
        "First Name": "Christen",
        "Last Name": "Hardin",
        "Address": "390-1605 Adipiscing Street",
        "City": "Oudergem",
        "Zip": "90085",
        "ID": "78046404"
    },
    {
        "First Name": "Uma",
        "Last Name": "Cunningham",
        "Address": "313-1839 Lorem Av.",
        "City": "San Cristóbal de la Laguna",
        "Zip": "99153",
        "ID": "27367690"
    }
]
}
```

and JS to ->

```
$.getJSON('SampleUserData.json', function(data) {

    var output="<ul>";
    $.each(data.result, function (index, val) {
        output+="<li>" + String(val.ID) + " " + String(val['Last Name']) + "--" +"</li>";
    });

    output+="</ul>";
    document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
});
```